# Decomposing a zoo object without the periodic error

Tags: r, time-series, xts, zoo

I'm trying to decompose a daily time series into the seasonal, trend, and remainder part. We can look at an example with google stocks provided by the fpp2 package :

Loading libraries

```
library(forecast)
library(lubridate) 
library(zoo)
library(fpp2)
```

Transform the time series of the package into a numeric vector

```
google <- as.numeric(goog)
```

Based on the documentation, google stocks go from 2013-02-25 to 2017-02-23

```
googZ <- zoo(google, seq(from = as.Date("2013-02-25"), to = as.Date("2017-02-23"), by = "days"))
```

Error in decompose(googZ) : time series has no or less than 2 periods

```
decompose(googZ)
```

> Error in decompose(googZ) : time series has no or less than 2 periods

This one works however and I'm not sure why the Google on is not

```
autoplot(decompose(AirPassengers))
str(AirPassengers)
```

I don't understand why is this happening as we clearly have and defined correctly our time series.
Note that I used the zoo package because ts can't handle daily time series.
Thank you very much !

Comment: The difference is between `frequency(googZ)` and `frequency(AirPassengers)` hence you get the error.

Comment: Your `googZ` is wrong, try instead `googZ <- zoo(google, seq(from = as.Date("2013-02-25"), by = "days", length.out = length(google)))`.

Comment: @RonakShah Okey you are right ! I understand  the frequency argument for a ts object (1,4 or 12) but how do you manage to set the frequency daily in zoo() ? I naively tried to set frequency = 365 but no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`decompose` requires

- a regularly spaced `ts` series
- the same number of points per period, e.g. 365 points per year assuming year is one period
- that the period be 1
- that the points within a period be deltat apart where delatt = 1/frequency and frequency is the number of points per period

`Date` class objects are represented as days since the Epoch (Jan 1, 1970).  Due to leap years `Date` objects do not have the same number of points per year, the difference between successive years is 365 or 366, not 1, and the points are 1 apart, not deltat apart.

What we can do to force fit it into a `ts` object is to take the first 365 days per year (on leap years this will drop Dec 31) and then use this.  Note that the `year` component of `POSIXlt` objects is the number of years since 1900 so we must add the 1900 back and the `yday` component is 0 for Jan 1st, 1 for Jan 2nd and so on to 364 for a non-leap year and 365 for a leap year.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)

lt <- as.POSIXlt(time(goog2))
tt <- with(lt, ts(coredata(goog2[yday < 365]), 
  start = year[1] + 1900 + yday[1]/365, frequency = 365))
autoplot(decompose(tt))
```

giving:

[image: screenshot]